# How to populate JComboBox from SqlServer

Tags: java, sql-server, jcombobox

I am trying to populate a JComboBox from data in SqlServer.  I am using WindowBuilder if that makes a difference.  This is the code I have so far.  I am very new to Java so I don't have any idea what to do.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class Customer extends  JFrame{

private JFrame frame;
private JTable table;
private JTable tblInformation;
private JTable tblHistory;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void NewScreen()
{
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Customer window = new Customer();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Customer() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 819, 656);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
    comboBox.setBounds(372, 28, 152, 22);
    frame.getContentPane().add(comboBox);

    JLabel lblCustomer = new JLabel("Select customer");
    lblCustomer.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    lblCustomer.setBounds(245, 30, 121, 16);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblCustomer);

    JLabel lblCustomerInformation = new JLabel("Information");
    lblCustomerInformation.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    lblCustomerInformation.setBounds(12, 74, 92, 16);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblCustomerInformation);

    JLabel lblHistory = new JLabel("History");
    lblHistory.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    lblHistory.setBounds(12, 334, 56, 16);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblHistory);

    JButton btnEdit = new JButton("Edit");
    btnEdit.setBounds(12, 569, 97, 25);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnEdit);

    JButton btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
    btnExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Welcome.main(null);
        }
    });
    btnExit.setBounds(690, 569, 97, 25);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnExit);

    JButton btnAdd = new JButton("Add");
    btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
        {
            String custIDString, firstName, lastName, companyName, phoneNumber, street, city, state, zip;
            int custID; 

            custIDString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter customer ID", "Customer ID", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            custID = Integer.parseInt(custIDString);

            firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter first name", "First Name", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            lastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter last name", "Last Name", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            companyName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter company name", "Company Name", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            phoneNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter phone number (xxx-xxx-xxx)", "Phone Number", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            street = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter street", "Street", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            city = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter city", "City", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            state = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter state", "State", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            zip = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter zip", "Zip", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }


    });
    btnAdd.setBounds(235, 569, 97, 25);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnAdd);

    table = new JTable();
    table.setBounds(257, 168, 137, -66);
    frame.getContentPane().add(table);

    tblInformation = new JTable();
    tblInformation.setBounds(12, 96, 422, 156);
    frame.getContentPane().add(tblInformation);

    tblHistory = new JTable();
    tblHistory.setBounds(12, 357, 422, 177);
    frame.getContentPane().add(tblHistory);

    JButton btnDelete = new JButton("Delete");
    btnDelete.setBounds(474, 569, 97, 25);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnDelete);
}
public class TestComboBox extends JComboBox
{
    private Connection sqlCon;
    private Statement st;

    public TestComboBox()
    {
        super();

        initComponents();
    }
    private void initComponents()
    {
        try
        {
            st = sqlCon.createStatement();
            loadComboBox();
        }
        catch (SQLException sqle)
        {
            System.out.println(sqle);
        }
    }
    public void loadComboBox()
    {
        this.removeAllItems();
        this.addItem("Please select");
        try
        {
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select FirstName, LastName from Customer");
            while (rs.next())
            {
                this.addItem(rs.getString("FirstName") + "" + rs.getString("LastName"));
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException sqle)
        {
            System.out.println(sqle);
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Take small steps.  First load the combo box with hard coded values.  Then get stuff from a database and dump it to the console.  Then put the two together.  You will learn more that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void loadCombo(){
    Vector vec = new Vector();

        try {
            resultset = //"resultst from database";
            while (resultset.next()) {
                vec.add(resultset.getString("table column"));
                }
                 yourCombo.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(vec)); 
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

well here is an example, what im doing here is getting `values` from `resultset` putting the values into a `vector` then im adding the `vector` inside the `combobox` try this.

Comment: its a `method` you can call at any point if you want to `load data` at the opening of `jframe` call this `method` at the `constructor`

Comment: resultset has an error.  So does the name of my combo box

Comment: whats the `error` is it a `compile error` you are getting

Comment: by the way your `comboBox`is not a `instance variable` its `instatiated` and
`declared` inside a `method` you should make that a `instance variable` inorder for other `methods` to `access` it

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about overriding toString method in classes? I'll try to explain.

If you have a class named Customers and attributes for this class are firstName and lastName (with setters and getters), then you could override toString method in Customers class like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return firstName;
}
```

Then you could create a class Example that returns a DefaultComboBoxModel like this:

```
public static DefaultComboBoxModel getCustomerModel() {
    DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select FirstName, LastName from Customer");
    while (rs.next()) {
        Customer c = new Customer();
        c.setFirstName(rs.getString("FirstName"));
        c.setLastName(rs.getString("LastName"));
        model.addElement(c);
    }
    return model;
}
```

Finally set your combobox model like this:

```
myComboBox.setModel(Example.getCustomerModel());
```

So in myComboBox you will see only the firstName of the customer and if you want to obtain a Customer from myComboBox object, then:

```
Customer c = (Customer) myComboBox.getSelectedItem();
```

Regards.

Comment: Is there a specific place in the code that this should go?

Comment: No. You must create classes separately. The first class is Customer where you have firstName, lastName attributes that you obtain from database. Then create a class Example or Database or the name you want and in this class is where you obtain the DefaultComboBoxModel and finally a class MyWindow where it goes the JComboBox that uses the class Example to obtain the model. The main idea of overriding toString metod is that you could decide what information want to see in JCombobox object and that every item from it represents a customer.